# Order by bigger of two Sql columns

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, sql-order-by, iqueryable

I have a SqlTable with 2 columns, DateInsert(no nullable) and DateUpdate(nullable).

Is there any way I can order by the newest datetime of both columns with c# linq??

I'm trying to do in a C# IQueryable with LINQ, so save the query into a memory list and reorder later is not and option, I need something sqlserver could understand and make the query in one step.

I tryed with query.OrderBy(x=>x.DateUpdate).ThenBy(x=>x.DateInsert) but its not works well...

The expected result is like the next example:

```
Item1: Insert: 2020-01-01 Update: null
Item2: Insert: 2019-01-01 Update: 2020-03-01
Item3: Insert: 2019-01-01 Update: 2019-05-01

Ordered Result: Item2->Item1->Item3
```

Thank tou for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get the maximum and order by that:

```cs
query.OrderBy(x=> x.DateUpdate>x.DateInsert?x.DateUpdate:x.DateInsert);
```